# aws: ACLS: not able to understand what the settings do

Tags: amazon-vpc

I am checking on of the subnets in a vpc created by someone.

I am not able to understand the below configuration

[image]

Why are they doing allow and also deny the same in both inbound and outbound

Answer (score 0):

From https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-network-acls.html

> The default network ACL is configured to allow all traffic to flow in and out of the subnets with which it is associated. Each network ACL also includes a rule whose rule number is an asterisk (*). This rule ensures that if a packet doesn't match any of the other numbered rules, it's denied. You can't modify or remove this rule.

So what you are seeing is default rule set.

NACL rules are evaluated in numerical order. When traffic matches a rule, the Allow/Deny is applied, and evaluation ends.

Therefore, the default rule that you show above Allows all traffic. No traffic falls through to the default rule.